# Align the same table with full join and union

Tags: sql, join, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, distinct, common-table-expression

I have the following database structure consists of 4 table and query in which represented  joins that are required there:

```
-- table 1
create TABLE TBL_1 (
   ID INT,
   GOODS_ID INT,
   CREATE_DATE DATE,
   TYPE VARCHAR
);

-- table 2
create TABLE TBL_2 (
   ID INT,
   SEC_ID INT,
   GOODS_ROL_ID INT,
   TYPE VARCHAR,
   RES_1 NUMBER,
    RES_2 NUMBER
);

-- goods table
create TABLE GOODS (
   ID INT,
   ROL_ID INT,
   NAME VARCHAR
);

-- sec table
create TABLE SEC (
   ID INT,
   NAME VARCHAR
);

-- query with business logic
SELECT t1.CREATE_DATE, t1.GOODS_ID, t2.SEC_ID, t2.GOODS_ROL_ID, t2.RES_1, t2.RES_2
FROM TBL_1 t1,
     TBL_2 t2,
     GOODS t3,
     SEC t4
WHERE t1.ID = t2.ID
AND t1.GOODS_ID = t3.ID
AND t2.GOODS_ROL_ID = t3.ROL_ID
AND t2.SEC_ID = t4.ID

Example values which can be in TBL_2:
ID,SEC_ID,GOODS_ROL_ID,TYPE,RES_1,RES_2
1,0,11,TYPE_1,10,15
2,0,22,TYPE_1,12,17
3,0,11,TYPE_2,14,13
4,0,22,TYPE_2,11,16
```

There is `TYPE` column which can have different value for the subset of *CREATE_DATE, GOODS_ID, SEC_ID, and GOODS_ROL_ID* columns,
and I want to align the results using something like a **full outer join (or union)** for the following columns *CREATE_DATE, GOODS_ID, SEC_ID, and GOODS_ROL_ID*.
In the output I expecting different columns created so output should looks like:

Expected result for query above:

```
CREATE_DATE,GOODS_ID,SEC_ID,GOODS_ROL_ID,TYPE,RES_1,RES_2,ALIGNED_RES_1,ALIGNED_RES_2
2012-01-01,1,0,11,TYPE_1,10,15,NULL,NULL
2012-01-01,1,0,22,TYPE_1,12,17,NULL,NULL
2012-01-01,1,0,11,TYPE_2,NULL,NULL,14,13
2012-01-01,1,0,22,TYPE_2,NULL,NULL,11,16
2012-01-02,1,0,11,TYPE_1,10,15,NULL,NULL
2012-01-02,1,0,22,TYPE_1,12,17,NULL,NULL
2012-01-02,1,0,11,TYPE_2,NULL,NULL,14,13
2012-01-02,1,0,22,TYPE_2,NULL,NULL,11,16
```

**UPD**
The following query doing what I am looking for but it leaving duplicated rows:

```
WITH aligned_data AS (
  SELECT t1.CREATE_DATE, t1.GOODS_ID, t2.SEC_ID, t2.GOODS_ROL_ID, t2.TYPE,
    t2.RES_1, t2.RES_2, t2.TYPE || '_ALIGNED' AS ALIGNED_TYPE,
    NULL::NUMBER AS ALIGNED_RES_1, NULL::NUMBER AS ALIGNED_RES_2
  FROM TBL_1 t1
  INNER JOIN TBL_2 t2 ON t1.ID = t2.ID
  INNER JOIN GOODS t3 ON t1.GOODS_ID = t3.ID AND t2.GOODS_ROL_ID = t3.ROL_ID
  INNER JOIN SEC t4 ON t2.SEC_ID = t4.ID
  UNION ALL
  SELECT t1.CREATE_DATE, t1.GOODS_ID, t2.SEC_ID, t2.GOODS_ROL_ID, NULL::VARCHAR,
    NULL::NUMBER, NULL::NUMBER, t2.TYPE,
    t2.RES_1 AS ALIGNED_RES_1, t2.RES_2 AS ALIGNED_RES_2
  FROM TBL_1 t1
  FULL OUTER JOIN TBL_2 t2 ON t1.ID = t2.ID
)
SELECT CREATE_DATE, GOODS_ID, SEC_ID, GOODS_ROL_ID,
  COALESCE(TYPE, ALIGNED_TYPE) AS TYPE,
  RES_1, RES_2, ALIGNED_RES_1, ALIGNED_RES_2
FROM aligned_data
ORDER BY CREATE_DATE, GOODS_ID, SEC_ID, GOODS_ROL_ID, TYPE;
```

Expected result for updated query above:

```
CREATE_DATE,GOODS_ID,SEC_ID,GOODS_ROL_ID,TYPE,RES_1,RES_2,ALIGNED_RES_1,ALIGNED_RES_2
2012-01-01,1,0,11,TYPE_1,10,15,NULL,NULL
2012-01-01,1,0,22,TYPE_1,12,17,NULL,NULL
2012-01-01,1,0,11,TYPE_1,NULL,NULL,10,15 <-- NOT EXPECTED DUPLICATE
2012-01-01,1,0,22,TYPE_1,NULL,NULL,12,17 <-- NOT EXPECTED DUPLICATE
2012-01-01,1,0,11,TYPE_2,NULL,NULL,14,13
2012-01-01,1,0,22,TYPE_2,NULL,NULL,11,16
2012-01-01,1,0,11,TYPE_2,14,13,NULL,NULL <-- NOT EXPECTED DUPLICATE
2012-01-01,1,0,22,TYPE_2,11,16,NULL,NULL <-- NOT EXPECTED DUPLICATE
```

Comment: Over 30 years ago SQL standards adopted explicit join syntax, please stop using commas as joins in the from clause.

Comment: Some sample data for all 4 tables is needed to run that query, and to be honest, not sure I understand how ALIGNED_RES_1,ALIGNED_RES_2 would get populated (what is the logic required?)

Comment: @PaulMaxwell provided updated query which is almost doing what I wanted but filling duplicates, can you please take a look ?

Comment: @PaulMaxwell ALIGNED_RES_1,ALIGNED_RES_2 are populated from RES_1 and RES_2 when aligned by  CREATE_DATE, GOODS_ID, SEC_ID, and GOODS_ROL_ID columns and for this set of columns when TYPE is different then ALIGNED_RES_1,ALIGNED_RES_2 should be populated by RES_1 and RES_2 instead of populating directly RES_1 and RES_2